# How to use the same variable in two classes

Tags: python

```
# I have this class:

class Test(webapp.RequestHandler):
    myList = []
    def get(self):
        s = [self.request.get('sentence')]
        self.myList.append(s)
        htmlcode1 = HTML.table(self.myList)
        myListLen = len(self.myList)
        lastItem = self.myList[myListLen-2]

# I want to add the following to delete the contents of `myList` when I enter 'delete' in the form:

class Delete(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        if s == ['delete']:
            del self.myList[:]
```

How can I use `self.myList` under `Delete()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would want to use

```
Test.myList
```

because myList is an attribute of the class, not a particular instance of that class.